# Generating VISA card numbers with VISA API

Tags: node.js

I've been doing some research and have been wondering how a company like privacy.com are able to generate VISA card numbers on the fly? I was looking at the VISA API and there's nothing publicly that I can find. Do they have some sort of special arrangement. I'm based in the UK and am Looking to build a service with a similar functionality, but can't seem to find any material on doing this.

Stripe also offer a service, but exclusively for US based customers. Are there any laws or regulations that I might be overlooking which prevent this being done in the UK?

```
VISA API  
https://developer.visa.com/apibrowser

https://privacy.com/ 
https://stripe.com/gb/issuing 
https://cards.emburse.com/pricing  (These guys piggy back off stripe's service)
```

Answer (score 1):

They probably use a service from virtual card providers. There are many, example: eNett is kinda popular with online travel agency https://www.enett.com/ They will provide you an API to create card with limit, expiration date, etc...

Comment: Oh I see, I've never heard of them. Thanks for the response, i'll check them out.